# Issue with BackgroundTransfer not saving the downloaded file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have an issue with the background transfer service:

I am trying to download a file from onedrive using BackgroundDownloader, the transfer seems to be effective (some bytes are transfered), but the transfer seems to never end, and at the end the file downloaded size is 0 bytes.
In addition, the transfer never ends because if I launch a second transfer, it never starts (except if i switch the network connectivity (wifi on/off)).

I have tried the same link in the background transfer sample from MS, it gets the same behavior. However I have used the same link in IE, and the transfer goes well.
I have tried with many files (mp3), the result is the same. I have also added:

```
download.CostPolicy = BackgroundTransferCostPolicy.Always;
```

but still same result. I have also tried on wifi, debug, release.

Any idea why the file would not be saved? (I have enough space on the SD card of course)

If no answer is found, does anyone know a good implementation of this background transfer service that I could use instead of the official one?

Comment: Usually this happens when the application is designed to transfer text data and you are trying to download binary data.

Comment: What do you mean by "designed to transfer text data"?

Comment: Downloading to an SD card was usually a source of troubles in Windows 8.1. This was improved in Windows 10 as described [here](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/02/networking-api-improvements-in-windows-10/) Or try to avoid downloading to an SD card.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will therefore upgrade to WP10 my phone